# PHP Encoding JSON Issue

Tags: php, arrays, json

I wanna json encode a PHP array to send it for a server, but the server **wants** it in **this format**:

```
[{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }]
```

But now my associative array after using json_encode() on it looks like this:

```
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version with the `[]` is an array of objects, you just have a single object.  Just create an array with that single object...

```
echo json_encode( [ $data ] );
```

gives...

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}]
```

Comment: Oh thanks I'm dummy it's an another array but not assosiative.. Thanks!

Comment: Just remember - If you see `[]` in JSON - it can't have anything but sequential numeric indexes starting from 0.  If any index is missing or a string it will be an object (`{}`).

Answer (score 0):

You can get first element of parsed json. like this:

```
$json = '[{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }]';

$parse = json_decode($json,true);

echo json_encode($parse[0]);
```